# how to send the value of "text box" even if it is grayed out/disabled in HTML?

Tags: html, fonts, textbox, javascript

I m doing like this in java script :

```
document.getElementById(XYZ).value = '32768';
document.getElementById(ABC).value = '32768 ';  
document.getElementById(XYZ).disabled = true;
document.getElementById(ABC).disabled = true;
```

when i m pressing submit it gives "0" as value.
BUT i want to retrieve above values.

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

readOnly is an option but it changes the FONT COLOUR from gray to black,
but i want gray colored text in readOnly textbox

any help!!!!

thanx !!!

Answer (score 2):

Disabling an element takes it out of the form. The value will not be transmitted.

The only solution is not disabling the element. Depending on what you want to do, for example  the [`readonly` property](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/readonly.html) could work for you.

Comment: ok, that means if em making the text box as readonly, still it sends the values ??

Comment: yes, but when i am refreshing the page it returns to normal textbox.

Comment: readOnly is an option but it changes the FONT COLOUR from gray to black, but i want gray colored text in readOnly textbox

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use [readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) attribute and some [CSS styles](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/colours/) to gray them out like you want.